# Prisma unable to be read in a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I have code to seed a database in a file called lifeseed.ts. I run it by typing node ./lifeseed.ts. For some reason it is giving me the error below. No clue why, you all got any questions?

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

main();

async function main() {
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Starting 2,999 Coin Transaction Seed Function");
    for (let i=0; i<=5; i++) {
        await prisma.coinTransaction.create({
            data: {
                userId: 1,
                coinId: 1,
                paymentId: 'test'+faker.datatype.uuid(),
                checkoutSessionCompleted: new Date('1-1-1969')
            }
        });
    }
    console.log("Seed Function Completed");
};
```

Here is the error below:

```
PS C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\prisma\seeds> node .\lifeseed.ts
Starting AI Community Seed Function
C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:27892
    return JSON.parse(await this.engine.dmmf());
                                        ^

TypeError: this.engine.dmmf is not a function
    at LibraryEngine.getDmmf (C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:27892:41)
    at async C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:35539:24
    at async PrismaClient._executeRequest (C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:36111:22)
    at async PrismaClient._request (C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:36082:16)
    at async C:\Users\jonat\facti\server\prisma\seeds\lifeseed.ts:107:29 {
  clientVersion: '4.8.0'
```

Comment: Try deleting your node modules folder, your lockfile, and reinstall your deps. If that doesn't fix it I got nuthin.

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thanks! Kind of annoying it needs to be nuked sometimes.